# Don't want double emacs in Unity

Tags: unity, emacs

I just brought up Ubuntu 18.04.4 with default GUI. I'm pretty sure the GUI manager is called Unity. (How do I find out?) First thing I did was install emacs via 'sudo apt install emacs'. Now, when I use the Apps menu (the 9 dots), and I search for 'emacs', I get results with two emacses: regular and terminal. [Pic: 2 emacses in search results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr9ic.png) But they appear to be doubled, since they have the same icon and the same name for the first bunch of characters, only differentiated by "(terminal)" at the end of one of their names.

Is there something I can do to get prevent this?  Can I delete just Emacs terminal (which I basically would never use) and keep regular GUI emacs?  Simpler would be to just say I don't want that app to appear in the apps menu choices - is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to make it (or any) application not show in your apps menu.

1. make a local copy of the `emacs25-term.desktop` file

   ```
   cp /usr/share/applications/emacs25-term.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
2. open the copy in a text editor of your choice and add the line

   ```
   NotShowIn=GNOME;
   ```
3. log out and back in to your desktop session

Comment: That worked great, and that's a great technique to know about generally. Thanks!